# Spark Dataframe write operation is missing some partition

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

We have a PySpark dataframe with 100 partition. When we do a write operation to save this dataframe as parquet file on HDFS location, we get 100 files most of the time. However sometime less than 100 files are generated and no exception or error is getting generated. Because of these missing files, we loose some records.

Spark DAG is showing all 100 tasks. So not able to figure out why this is happening.

**Troubleshoot 1**:- Added the code to print partition wise count before writing the dataframe. Code has printed the 100 partition with non-zero records(evenly distributed ) which proves there is no empty partition.

Comment: Missing files does not mean missing records/data, for troubleshooting check the count discrepancy between total records in  PySpark dataframe and total records from all the parquet files generated by specific execution.

Comment: I think there's less partitions is because some partitions are empty, so spark will not right them, that's it :)

Comment: Sorry for late reply. The scenario occurred again in production. AS part of debugging, I have printed the partition wise count of dataframe. It shows 100 partition with non-zero records in each partition. I have also checked the tasks for underline job created while doing parquet write operation.  So there are 100 tasks which are getting executed successfully.